# Using IN Element with other Elements in SPQuery

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, caml, spquery

I'm trying to retrieve items from list using this Query:

```
query.Query = 
@"<Where>
    <And>
        <And>
            <Geq>
                <FieldRef Name='Date' /><Value Type='DateTime' IncludeTimeValue='TRUE'>" + SPUtility.CreateISO8601DateTimeFromSystemDateTime(dateFrom) + @"</Value>
            </Geq>
            <Leq>
                <FieldRef Name='Date' /><Value Type='DateTime' IncludeTimeValue='TRUE'>" + SPUtility.CreateISO8601DateTimeFromSystemDateTime(dateTo) + @"</Value>
            </Leq>
        </And>
        <In>
            <FieldRef Name='Employee' LookupId='TRUE' />
                <Values>
                    <Value Type='int'>1</Value>
                    <Value Type='int'>3</Value>
                </Values>
        </In>
    </And>
</Where>";
```

On runtime i get the following exception: 
**SPException: One or more field types are not installed properly. Go to the list settings page to delete these fields**
on line `List.GetItems(query)`.

If i modify SPQuery like this:

```
query.Query =
@"<Where>
    <And>
        <Geq>
            <FieldRef Name='Date' /><Value Type='DateTime' IncludeTimeValue='TRUE'>" + SPUtility.CreateISO8601DateTimeFromSystemDateTime(dateFrom) + @"</Value>
        </Geq>
        <Leq>
            <FieldRef Name='Date' /><Value Type='DateTime' IncludeTimeValue='TRUE'>" + SPUtility.CreateISO8601DateTimeFromSystemDateTime(dateTo) + @"</Value>
        </Leq>
    </And>
</Where>";
```

or this:

```
query.Query =
@"<Where>
    <In>
        <FieldRef Name='Employee' LookupId='TRUE' />
            <Values>
                <Value Type='int'>1</Value>
                <Value Type='int'>3</Value>
            </Values>
    </In>
</Where>";
```

everything is working perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in reusing `SPQuery` object, surprisingly. So I create a new `SPQuery` and everything is OK.